# Cannot find symbol method FindViewById(int) with extends AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to assign a button to a Button variable using FindViewById like this:

```
Button dotBtn = (Button)FindViewById(R.id.dotBtn);
```

I get an error

> Cannot find symbol method FindViewById(int)

What is the problem? Does it have something to do with the extends AppCompatActivity? I mean with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `findViewById` not `FindViewById`. Small `f`

Answer (score 0):

try this 
Button dotBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dotBtn);

Answer (score 0):

It  has nothing to do with AppCompatActivity. Actually it has to be : "findViewById" with small 'f'  and not Capital 'F'.